# Word choice: Gent, Gent's or Gents?

Tags: word-choice, slang

I'm going to name my new business, I got an idea from another company called **"ZZZ Men Supply"**  and come up with **"XXX Gentlemen Supply"** for my business. Since the word Gentlemen slightly longer I want to use the abbreviation for it, which one is better: **"XXX Gent Supply"**, **"XXX Gent's Supply"** or **"XXX Gents Supply"**?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very similar to another about [*Mens* or *Men's*](/q/112420) -- different word but the same principle. I wouldn't use *Gent* unless you are actually selling them.

Comment: If you go for the apostrophe, put it _after_ the 's'. Presumably you hope to be selling to more than one gentleman!

Comment: In Britain these days, we only use 'Gents' in connection with public toilets for men, usually containing urinals.

Comment: @AndrewLeach lol, of course, I'm not going sell them :) I'm selling men's products

Comment: @KateBunting Is without apostrophe acceptable? I would go with gents supply then

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That really makes me think twice to use the term "Gents", any other alternative words?

Comment: @Rifki Come on, you've been around long enough to know that's not the sort of question to ask, especially in comments. If you want to ask that as a question, fine, but [we have guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: << Gentlemens Supplies >> (chevrons merely to set apart without implying any quotes, apostrophisation etc) is quite acceptable nowadays. Some may complain that you're dropping a needed apostrophe; tell them you're using the emancipated usage of a plural-form-where-it-makes-sense attributive noun and refer them to the countless  << working mens clubs >> (eg Woodhouses Working Mens Club) and many << writers guilds >> (eg the Chippewa Valley Writers Guild) that have adopted this usage.